# How to take gradient of vector function? (Electric field to be precise)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Am i going mad? I don't remember ever having to take gradient of a vector function before. It cant be the same thing as divergence right?

Edit: In griffiths intro to EM, equation 4.5, he states that the force on dipole due to non-uniform external electric field is
$\vec{F} = (\vec{p} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{E}$

$\vec{E}$ is the electric field, and we are taking gradient of a vector field?

Comment: Can you show us an example? The notation $\nabla \cdot f$ is sometimes used for the divergence of a vector field $f$. Perhaps that's what you've encountered.

Comment: edited the question, and yes there is no $\cdot$ between the paraenthese terms and $\vec{E}$

Comment: Griffiths explains this notation on the bottom of the previous page.  It means that $\vec{F}$ is the vector field whose $x$ coordinate equals $(\nabla E_x) \cdot \vec{p}$.  It does not mean to take the gradient of $\vec{E}$.

Comment: so we would treat E as if it were a scalar. Ok, but out of curiosity what is the gradient of a vector field? I read on another post that it gives you a tensor?

Comment: The *differential* of a vector field is a tensor, but it is usually not called a "gradient".  It's just some object that encapsulates all the partial derivatives of all the components of the vector field.  We usually reserve the word "gradient" for the operation on scalar-valued functions only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation means
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} &= p_x \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial x} + p_y \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial y} + p_z \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial z}
\end{align}
So you kind of "take the dot product of $\mathbf{p}$ and $\nabla$" and apply the resulting differential operator to $\mathbf{E}$.

Comment: Griffiths asks the reader to work this out in Problem 1.21, and you can also infer it from the derivation immediately preceding (4.5).